# How to alternate between startService() and stopService() using onClick?

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

How do i alternate between this two intents on a surfaceview and create the sort of graphical effect seen in youtube during start/pause when recording a video?

-->stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceRecording.class));
-->startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceRecording.class);

```
public void onClick(View v)
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some reason why the following idea won't work?

```
if (serviceRunning) {
  serviceRunning = false;
  stopService(...);
} else {
  serviceRunning = true;
  startService(...);
}
```

Comment: Yes your method works fine :) Thanks!! Although now i'm able to alternate between startservice() and stopservice() on the surfaceview but the surfaceview isn't showing the graphical detail shown in youtube tap a YouTube video on the video itself it kinda flashes the play or pause button over the vide when i start/stop the video recording process...

Comment: could could help in how i'm going to achieve the sort of effect i mention above?